# Fingerprint reader got stopped working in X1 carbon 8th gen running Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, lenovo, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

The fingerprint reader was working fine previously on my X1 carbon 8th gen running Ubuntu 22.04. A few days back I noticed that it is not working and I suspect that this could be due to OS update as I frequently OS update the laptop. `lsusb` lists the fingerprint reader as follows,

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc. Prometheus MIS Touch Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b6cb Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and `sudo service fprintd status` output is as follows

```
○ fprintd.service - Fingerprint Authentication Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fprintd.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:fprintd(1)

Jun 23 20:30:13 kasunsi fprintd[7147]: Device reported an error during identify for enroll: Unexpected result from device 502
Jun 23 20:30:21 kasunsi fprintd[7147]: Authorization denied to :1.169 to call method 'Claim' for device 'Synaptics Sensors': Device was already claimed
Jun 23 20:30:53 kasunsi systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jun 23 20:31:24 kasunsi systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
Jun 23 20:31:24 kasunsi systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
Jun 23 20:31:37 kasunsi fprintd[9001]: identify has failed: 502
Jun 23 20:31:37 kasunsi fprintd[9001]: Device reported an error during identify for enroll: Unexpected result from device 502
Jun 23 20:31:55 kasunsi fprintd[9001]: identify has failed: 502
Jun 23 20:31:55 kasunsi fprintd[9001]: Device reported an error during identify for enroll: Unexpected result from device 502
Jun 23 20:32:24 kasunsi systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

the output for `uname -r` is as follows,

```
5.19.0-45-generic
```

How can I get this fixed?

Note: Recently I got my laptop keyboard replaced by the vendor as few of the keys were not working and they have replaced the keyboard with the entire top panel without the touchpad and fingerprint sensor as I could see wear marks on them.